# Android okhttp3 Handshake failed with jetty backend using https

Tags: java, android, https, okhttp, embedded-jetty

I have an app in which I make POST requests with okhttp3 to send files and get an answer. The backend uses jetty and it works fine, when I make http requests. But when I try to change the configuration to https programmatically (you can see it in the commented try block), it fails. I get this Exception:

```
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:434)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:302)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:270)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:162)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at app.com.myapp.myUploadService$UpdateTask.sendToBackend(UploadService.java:270)
    at app.com.myapp.myUploadService$UpdateTask.uploadFiles(UploadService.java:226)
W/System.err:     at app.com.myapp.myUploadService$UpdateTask.doInBackground(UploadService.java:133)
    at app.com.myapp.myUploadService$UpdateTask.doInBackground(UploadService.java:118)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x724d289a00: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.c:522 0x724d2383a0:0x00000001)
error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO (external/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake_client.c:889 0x724b9318a6:0x00000000)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:357)
    ... 29 more
```

here is the backend code:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server = server = new Server(8082);

// servlet handlers
ServletContextHandler servletContext =
        new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
servletContext.setContextPath("/");

// jersey
ResourceConfig rConfig = new ResourceConfig();
rConfig.packages("com.mypackage.package");
ServletHolder jersey = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(rConfig));
servletContext.addServlet(jersey, "/*");

// IN THIS TRY BLOCK, I TRY TO CONFIGURE THE SERVER TO HTTPS. WITHOUT IT
// IT WORKS, BUT IS HTTP.
try {
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

    char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
    keystore.load(null, password);

    // Store away the keystore.
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileoutputStream("ks.keystore");
    keystore.store(fos, password);
    fos.close();

    SslContextFactory cf = new SslContextFactory();
    cf.setKeyStore(keystore);
    cf.setKeyStorePassword("password");

    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
    config.setSecureScheme("https");
    config.setSecurePort(8082);

    HttpConfiguration sslConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration(config);
    sslConfiguration.addCustomizer(new SecureRequestCustomizer());
    ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server,
            new SslConnectionFactory(cf, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.toString()),
            new HttpConnectionFactory(sslConfiguration));
    sslConnector.setPort(8082);
    sslConnector.setName("secured");
    server.setConnectors(new Connector[]{sslConnector});
} catch (Exception e){
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}

// add handlers to HandlerList
HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
handlers.addHandler(servletContext);

// add HanderList to server
server.setHandler(handlers);
```

And the client (android app) does this:

```
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(https://urltomyserver:8082)
    .post(requestBody)
    .build();

    // THE FOLLOWING LINE CAUSES THE EXCEPTION
    try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
         //do stuff
    }...
```

I just want to use https so the content and the url query parameters are encrypted. No ultra fancy stuff.
I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: What version of Android?  What version of Jetty?  What version of Java are you running Jetty on?  I ask because you might not have an overlap of TLS features between your choices.  (old Android versions cannot connect to today's secure servers due to lack of common cipher suites between them.  The server side would need to be configured to allow insecure cipher suites to enable your Android code to connect to it, jeopardizing all users on your server!)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Android API 26 (8.0), Jetty 9.4.12.RC2. As you can see in my Android code, I don't use any kind of key to communicate with the server. Is that normal?